# How to have filename with date in PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler JBoss 7?

Tags: java, jboss

This is my config.

```
<log:periodic-rotating-file-handler name="ROTATINGFILE" autoflush="true">
      <log:formatter>
        <log:named-formatter name="JSON"/>
      </log:formatter>
      <file path="/opt/jboss/keycloak/logs/server.log"/>
      <log:level name="INFO"/>
      <log:suffix value="-yyyyMMdd"/>
      <append value="true"/>
    </log:periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

Now it is server.log.20200101 rotating file.

Is there a way to have combined file name like server-20200101.log ?

Thanks

Comment: If what you need is to always have a filename ending in `.log` you can simply add the `.log` to the suffix, but then you'll get `server.log-20200101.log`. I don't think `server.log` / `server-20200101.log` can be achieved by configuration of this handler

Comment: Ehh, Means need to write custom handler and this i am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by

```
<log:suffix value=".yyyyMMdd'.log'"/>
```

SimpleDateFormat: Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single quote.